# Integration test class name conflict on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, factory-bot

In my application there's a model called `App`. I'm trying to test my application with `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`.

To create data for the test I use `FactoryGirl` like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :app, class: App do
    name "a_test"
    about "magic_app"
    app_key "1213"
  end

end
```

Then in my test I instantiate one app like this:

```
setup do
  @app = create(:app)
end
```

Now when I run the test I get an error because there's already a class named `App`:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for #<App:0x00000004c985e8>`

I think namespacing can fix this - renaming the model is not an option - but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your instance variable, for example:

```
setup do
  @my_app = create(:app)
end
```

Comment: That works! Wouldn't expect there's a global variable called `app`.

Comment: @TTT It's not a global variable. It's an instance variable, but it's used in `Rack` (and thus `ActionDispatch`) internals.